# openwebkitsharp Text Search function

Tags: c#, winforms, open-webkit-sharp

I am trying to implement a Text Search function. Is there a Find function in openwebkitsharp. I tried

```
uint totalmatches; 
webKitBrowser1.Find(textBox1.Text, out totalmatches);
```

The Visual Studio IDE couldn't find the Find function. Am i missing an assembly reference or something else.